# Webscraping the data to dataframe

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping

Good Day.

I have created the code in python to extract the web content and create into the data frame.
I have created the output but unable to create the dataframe as for example managed by: Republic polytechnic
Last updated: June 27, 2018, 14:52 (SGT)

I have created the code in the post, request your advise to create the dataframe from the output.

### Code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
page = requests.get("https://data.gov.sg/dataset/republic-polytechnic-part-time-courses")
page = requests.get("https://data.gov.sg/dataset/republic-polytechnic-part-time-courses")
print(soup.prettify())
page = requests.get("https://data.gov.sg/dataset/republic-polytechnic-part-time-courses")
page = requests.get("https://data.gov.sg/dataset/republic-polytechnic-part-time-courses")
tonight = items[3]
print(tonight.prettify())
dataset = tonight.find(class_="dataset-description").get_text()
managedby = tonight.find(class_="table").get_text()
print(dataset)
print(managedby)
```

---

### output:

List of RP Part-Time Courses

Managed By
Republic Polytechnic

Last Updated
June 27, 2018, 14:52 (SGT)

Created
February 26, 2018, 10:57 (SGT)

Coverage
January 1, 2017 to December 31, 2017

Frequency
Annual

Comment: what kind of output you want to see in your data frame?? I hope you know that the above code is not complete as it is missing a few pieces.

Comment: Hiya,

I got the output, can i convert the output into the dataframe?

Comment: why not? depending upon the format of your output, you can create the data frame using the right syntax for [pd.DataFrame()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)

Comment: @Kumar, I have executed the command as below:

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(managedby)
print (df)

however getting the error, is there any modification required?

Comment: you need to show the error you are getting and the value of `managedby` you are feeding to pd.DataFrame(). (see)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve]